# How to use Entity FrameWork ToLookUp()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My current query for my grid's ItemSource is dramatically slow. It current has 8 includes. I've read that it can be sped up if I use multiple queries instead of using `Includes()`. Referencing from http://mikee.se/Archive.aspx/Details/entity_framework_pitfalls,_include_20140101

I'm written the queries to my database below

```
var loans = unitOfWork.Context.Loans.AsNoTracking().ToList();
var clientAccount = unitOfWork.Context.ClientAccounts.AsNoTracking().ToList();
var business = unitOfWork.Context.Businesses.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

I'm trying to write the next the ToLookUp part but I'm not quite sure what the proper syntax/way is to do it.

Loan.cs Model

```
public int? Client_Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Client_Id")]
public virtual Business Client { get; set; }

public int? ClientAccount_Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ClientAccount_Id")]
public virtual ClientAccount ClientAccount { get; set; }
```

Business.cs Model

```
 public virtual ICollection<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
```

I was able to implement a lookup code if it has a 1 to 1 relationship. For example, a loan can only have 1 client account.

```
var clientAccount = unitOfWork.Context.ClientAccounts.AsNoTracking().ToLookup(x => x.LoanId)
```

But if it's not exactly 1 to 1 I'm not sure how I would implement the Lookup and Contains. A business can have multiple loans.

```
var business = unitOfWork.Context.Businesses.AsNoTracking().ToLookup(x => x.Loans);
```

Now how do I set the contains? I tried below but that didn't work.

```
loan.Client = business.Contains(loan.Id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looup - is a data structure that has many values for one key (like `Dictionary<T,IEnumerable<K>>`).
So, when you write `ToLookup(x => x.LoanId)` it means, that you grouped your entities by LoandId and you expect MANY entities.
So, you need something like:

```
var loans = unitOfWork.Context.Loans.AsNoTracking().ToLookup(o=>o.Client_Id);
var clientAccount = unitOfWork.Context.ClientAccounts.AsNoTracking().ToList();
foreach(var cilent in clientAccount)
{
    client.Loans = loans[Client.ID].ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I have so many collections, I would have to do the same for all collection properties?? and my foreach is loans, I have to set loans.Client = (business query)....

Comment: @Master 8 is not so many. You can load some collections with Inlude, and  others via their own queries and Lookup method